# The volume can't be ejected because it's currently in use

Tags: macos, external-disk, eject, disk-volume

After working with an external USB backup disk I want to cleanly unmount the drive. When pressing the 'eject' button Finder warns me with the message:

- "**The volume can't be ejected because it's currently in use.**"

or

- "**The disk "Diskname" wasn't ejected because one or more programs may be using it.**".

or when trying to use the Terminal: `umount /Volumes/Diskname`

- "**umount(/Volumes/Diskname): Resource busy -- try 'diskutil unmount'**"

As far as I am aware, I am not using this disk but Finder says I do, so I must be wrong. I prefer a clean unmount of the drive. As I am in the middle of doing multiple tasks, logging out and logging in is not preferred as is the installation of third party software.

Terminal command `lsof` might be of use here, but personally I think this is too complex for such a 'simple' problem and to be honest, I do not know how to use it properly.

My question: How do I know what program is using my drive so I can properly quit that program and eject my drive?

[image: The volume can't be ejected because it's currently in use.]
[image: The disk "Camel" wasn't ejected because one or more programs may be using it.]
[image: The disk "Mammtoh" wasn't ejected because one or more programs...]
[image: xkcd]

Comment: "As far as I am aware, I am not using this disk but Finder says I do, so I must be wrong." You trust machines too much. ;-) Often, computers are wrong and we humans are right.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I am right? ;)

Comment: Opposite question : [*apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52959/how-do-i-not-accidentally-eject-external-drives*](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52959/how-do-i-not-accidentally-eject-external-drives)

Comment: And if Spotlight is the culprit, save yourself some repetition: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/211616/15417

Comment: @John2095 in my comment under the answer you linked to, I detailed the error message I got when trying it. Time Machine drives cannot not be indexed, even in Terminal

Comment: Sometimes you just have to yank the cable. I think the Mac OS Journaled format prevents you from suffering data loss if you pull the cable [citation needed]

Answer (score 171, accepted):

`lsof` is indeed your best bet. The fastest and easiest way would be this :-

```
sudo lsof /Volumes/myDrive
```

(be sure to run with `sudo` otherwise [it probably won't work](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104842/the-volume-cant-be-ejected-because-its-currently-in-use#comment164077_104850) as intended)

It can take a couple minutes to run, but once it's complete, it gives you a list of open files on the disk. The output will look something like this:

```
COMMAND    PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF  NODE NAME
mds         89  root   19r   DIR   52,3      432     2 /Volumes/Photos
mds         89  root   23r   DIR   52,3      432     2 /Volumes/Photos
Finder     681 alans   14r   DIR   52,3      432     2 /Volumes/Photos
QuickLook 2158 alans    9r   REG   52,3  1141591 78651 /Volumes/Photos/_tmp_iphone_10_backup/APC_1546.JPG
```

In this case, it's the `QuickLook` application that has a file open. Closing the application directly is the best way to fix the issue. However, that's not always possible. For example, QuickLook doesn't show up as an application you can get to in the Dock.

If you can't close the application manually, you can use the `kill` command to terminate it from the command line. To do that, use the `PID` from the second column as the ID to kill. From the above example, it would be:

```
kill 2158
```

Note that sometimes that doesn't work and a more aggressive form of `kill` must be used. Here's a series of escalating aggressiveness (using the example PID of 2158):

```
kill 2158
sudo kill 2158
sudo kill -INT 2158
sudo kill -KILL 2158
```

You should be able to eject the disk once the process/application has been killed.

One final note, `lsof` can take a minute or two. It can also hang, but you should give it at least a few minutes before you decide that's what happened.

Also, sometimes the base command `sudo lsof /Volumes/myDrive` won't find anything. If that happens, try adding the `+D` argument (i.e. `sudo lsof +D /Volumes/myDrive`). That will do a top down scan of the disk. It'll take longer, but it should pick up anything that's causing the disk to be un-ejectable.

(*Hat tip to [Alec Jacobson's post](http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=649) for extra details.*)

Comment: I found this as well, but I hoped someone has a non terminal solution. If not, you'll get your plus one ;)

Comment: [lsof without sudo may **not** produce the required output](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/76305/8546).

Comment: → Paul: I'd suggest you to improve your suggested command as:
`/usr/bin/sudo lsof /Volumes/myDrive`

Comment: @danielAzuelos, why should one need super user rights for listing mounts?

Comment: @CousinCocaine please follow the link in my comment above. You'll be able to see for yourself.

Comment: Oh excellent, I did lsof without sudo which gives a totally different set of results.

Comment: Yep, sudo is definitely needed in a lot of cases. In my case this revealed that it was due to Spotlight trying to index the disk, so the solution was to disable Spotlight for the disk, then manually stop/restart Spotlight.

Comment: `sudo lsof /Volumes/drive` is much faster than `sudo lsof | grep /Volumes/drive`

Comment: What do you do if your drive has spaces in its name? (self-answer: put its name in double-quotes)

Comment: When I used lsof to find out why a drive couldn't unmount immediately, I needed to use `sudo`.  Without it, I wasn't getting enough information.  In the end, it turned out to be cloud backup software began backing up files on the drive when I didn't expect it.  I solved the problem by pausing the backup.  Then I could unmount the drive.

Comment: When killing a process, I send these signals in order of increasing aggression: `TERM` (the default), `HUP`, `QUIT`, `ABRT`, `INT`, `KILL` (which is guaranteed to work). It's worth waiting several seconds after each, as it can take a while for a process to shut down if it's blocked waiting for IO.

Comment: Absolutely absurd that macOS doesn't have an easy way to identify these processes and stop them. Disconnecting external hard drives from macOS basically has a 100% failure rate for me, and has had so for as long as I can recall (~10 years).

Answer (score 38):

Have you tried `$ diskutil unmount /Volumes/Diskname` ?

Or `$ diskutil unmount force /Volumes/Diskname` ?

As the [manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/umount.8.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/8/umount) points out:

> Due to the complex and interwoven nature of Mac OS X, umount may fail often.  It is recommended that
>        diskutil(1) (as in, "diskutil unmount /mnt") be used instead.

If your volume has spaces in the name, be sure to escape the spaces with `\`, eg:

```
$ diskutil unmount /Volumes/Disk\ Name
```

Or use quotes to avoid confusion.

```
$ diskutil unmount "/Volumes/Disk Name"
```

Comment: I believe I tried this and it did not work. But next time I'll try it again and update my post accordingly.

Comment: Your example has quotes, not apostrophes. Which is a good thing.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco: Thanks for pointing that out, I made corrections to the answer. Good catch!

Comment: Worked ->      sudo diskutil unmount force /Volumes/Diskname

Comment: @tgkprog Glad to hear it, also thanks for the `sudo` command, that may help others as well.

Comment: This provided the process id I had to `kill`.

Comment: It should go without saying, but this forcing an unmount should be avoided except as a last resort, and shouldn't be needed if you use the sudo lsof approach as suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 19):

Your problem is probably caused by the process `mds` : Spotlight indexing your disk.

[I have this problem, and I have not found a solution (yet).](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142459/how-to-eject-my-external-drive-when-my-mac-refuses-because-of-spotlight)

Comment: This is how to disable/re-enable spotlight indexing: http://www.iclarified.com/49187/how-to-disable-and-reenable-spotlight-indexing-on-your-mac

Comment: I also found that mds service using it. I tried to disable the mds service for flash drive using "sudo mdutil -i off /Volumes/16GB" but it also did not helped. I had to relaunch the Finder using "Option+Click" on FInder.

Answer (score 7):

You could try the donationware application "[What's Keeping me?](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/products/wkm/wkm.html)" that shows what process/application is using the volume/folder/file.

This program is certified by the developer for Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard, but the [RoaringApps page](http://roaringapps.com/app:2218) for this application lists it as working fine on OS X 10.7 Lion and OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion.

> #### About What's Keeping Me?
>
> Have you ever have the problem where you can’t empty the Trash or eject a disk because something is preventing you? Usually the reason is because some application has a file open, and thus you can’t get rid of the disk or trash the file. That’s why we made What’s Keeping Me! What’s Keeping Me will identify the application that is holding the item open. You can then use What's Keeping Me to quit the problem application (or kill it if needed) so you can perform your task. What’s Keeping Me includes an Automator workflow so you can perform searches directly from the Finder too!

Comment: This looks like valid software, but I really prefer OS X native solutions.

Comment: By native you mean something Apple provides? There's nothing like that on the GUI front. Plus, WKM has been around for several years.

Comment: Thanks for your addition. Native is not the correct word, what I meant was 'non-third party'. WKM is a nice solution, but personally I prefer lsof.

Comment: Just tested the app in High Sierra and it still works. It's also 64-bit.

Comment: Links are dead.

Answer (score 4):

Try to relaunch the Finder. Here it works

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted; In my case, QuickLook and mds both had a hold on it (despite no active finder windows open). I could restart mds, but `qlmanage -r` said it was "resetting quicklookd" but it still held the file open according to `lsof +D /path/to/volume`. A relaunch of the finder cleared it up and I was able to eject the volume.

Answer (score 3):

I've had this message *despite being sure there are no open files on the volume*. I checked this with [Why Not Unmount](http://www.tlensing.org/pub/artefacts/whynotunmount.html), a GUI tool that can indicate open files on a disk.

In my case, it was a sign that the file system is corrupt. Running Disk Utility (or if that wasn't enough, DiskWarrior) solved the problem and made the disk ejectable again.

Comment: In my case, the system was not corrupt.

Comment: Seems unlikely. More likely Spotlight, or some other app or service has a lock on the disk.

Comment: Link is dead now

Answer (score 3):

*NOTE: `fseventer` works until OS X 10.10 Yosemite and the developer's page  http://www.fernlightning.com meanwhile got offline. Hence the product links were removed. With `brew cask install fseventer` it may still be available on elder macOS versions.*

**There is a GUI alternative** to the CLI app `lsof`:
`fseventer` is a great file system access monitoring utility for **various purposes**. It runs with super user permissions (`sudo`), so it sees all read/write access of all mounted file systems, and presents them in a very clear overview.

**My experience:** I had a Volume which constantly could not be ejected properly (as in the OP's screenshots), and always needed a "force eject", sometimes even a forceful physical disconnection (nor recommended! could damage your filesystem(s) on that disk) or a system shutdown to bypass that brute method.

**My fix:** Summarized: *The ejection issue can be caused by corrupted or legacy file content on that Volume. Removing the troubled content can fix this permanently.* In detail:

1. Determine which file is accessed (with `lsof` or 
   `fseventer`). *In my case it was a Classic Mac OS file with a resource fork that remained open, likely as some background disk parsing process (Spotlight, QuickLook, or thelike) hung on it.*
2. Backup that troubling data into a file archive (which preserves (Classic) Mac specific resource data). *I simply used Finder's native "Compress" function from it's context menu.*
3. Delete the troubled file/folder.

   - With Finder as usual. *Likely this will fail, as it's a "troubled file/folder".*
   - With Finder plus holding down ALT while emptying the Trash. *This creates a little more force, but likely it will still fail.*
   - Through the Terminal with `sudo rm -R /path/to/troublesome/FileOrFolder`. *This eventually worked after Finder's delete attempts have failed.*
4. Try unmounting the volume again. *It may still fail, as the background processes, which failed, could be still in a irrecoverable state*.
5. Restart. Then try unmounting again. *From then forth the Volume worked fine again. Normal mounting, unmounting, read/write operations. Only when a file was indeed open by a user process, unmounting was prevented. Perfectly normal behaviour again.*

Answer (score 2):

Both the command line solution and What's Keeping Me work great.

To recap, command line in terminal is:

```
sudo lsof | grep /Volumes/myDrive
```

The GUI application is What's Keeping Me, ~~available at Hamsoft Engineering]~~ Thomas Templeman[1](https://apps.tempel.org/WhatsOpen/).

Screenshots of both with the same search going on.

[image: Command line output]
[image: GUI for What's Keeping Me]

I prefer the command line just slightly, as it's always there with you. On the other hand, What's Keeping Me is quicker and easier to use if you've got it installed.

Answer (score 0):

Solution
Make sure all programs are closed.
Click the Apple icon in the top left of the screen, then click Force Quit.
In the list click Finder.
Now click the Relaunch button.
Then try ejecting the drive again.

Comment: Did you see this solution work?

Comment: Or a simpler way… Use the `sudo lsof…` method described in the accepted solution, find the application that's causing the trouble, then close that specific application.

Answer (score -4):

I restarted my Mac and that fixed it :-)

Comment: I prefer a clean unmount of the drive. As I am in the middle of doing multiple tasks, logging out and logging in is not preferred as is the installation of third party software.

Comment: Thanks for a big tech helpline answer and a laugh. You should work for Microsoft customer support!