# How to eject a disk on macOS when it says programs are using it but this is not true?

Tags: macos, hard-drive

I want to eject an external 1 TB FAT32 disk on macOS 13.1, but when pressing the eject icon it says:

```
The disk MYDISK wasn't ejected because one or more programs may be using it
```

Is it OK to do "Force eject", or might I risk that `fsck_msdos` will run again? (It just did run, took a very long time after I just tried to clean the Trash. Nothing else).

Running:

```
sudo lsof /Volumes/MYDISK
```

does not return anything.

So what is going on? Why is macOS lying to me?
And how can I really remove/eject that disk safely?

Comment: I had situations in the past where `lsof /Volumes/mount` didn't return anything but `lsof | grep /Volumes/mount` did.

Comment: Oh F#####CK.  A billion of these shit useless nonsense mds processes!!!
Kill one of them, there will be two more. 
How can I solve that? Is there ANY way to stop all these stupid mds processes??

Comment: Ah found a solution from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142459/how-to-eject-my-external-drive-when-my-mac-refuses-because-of-spotlight/142666: `sudo killall mds`. Now I need to figure out how to remove the trash on that drive ...

Comment: This happens to me from time to time and when it does and I have no more apps that are doing anything on the drive nor are any copy operations in place. I use the more pragmatic rule that says if I'm not using the drive it is not in use and force eject it. Never had a problem doing that.

Comment: Did you try force-quit Finder? Or just do a hard restart.

Comment: Finder isn't in charge of the process, only the notifier, & hard rebooting is going to interrupt potentially important processes.

Comment: You say: "Is there ANY way to stop all these stupid mds processes?"  Try telling Time Machine to not index that file system. "System Preferences >> Time Machine >> Options >> Exclude these items from Backups" I think will get you there.  (details different with each release)